# Open a text file and make a dictionnary variable

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I would like to make this text file as a dictionnary. 
Like this:

```
{1: [37, 79, ..., 196], ..., 200: [149,...,35]}
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVA8t.jpg)

I used a picture, but normaly, it's a text file. 
Thanks for your help !!

Dropbox link of the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvvga3pypy8drm2/kargerMinCut.txt?dl=0

Comment: Can you post your text file?

Comment: where the text file is written? can you access that method?

Comment: How to post a text file? I didn't know I could

Comment: How is your text file generated? If it is still possible to adapt how it is written, I would recommend using the JSON format. This way transforming it into a dictionary will be a piece of cake in python.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited with a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('filename') as f:
    d = {k + 1: list(map(int, l.split())) for k, l in enumerate(f)}
```